# How to make trackpad scrolling work in tkinter on Lenovo?

Tags: tkinter

Following simple tkinter text can be scrolled with my mouse wheel but not with my trackpad. Any ideas how to make trackpad scrolling work? My platform is Win 7, Py 3.4 (64 bit), Tk 8.6.1, Lenovo T420

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

window = Tk()
text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window)
text.grid()
window.mainloop()
```

UPDATE. Looks like it's my Lenovo's problem. Trackpad scrolling works fine on Mac Book Pro and on Dell Latitude E5430. Still, the ideas how to fix this are welcome. I updated trackpad drivers, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to bind the mousewheel event, It's not documented below but that is still a good resource for the bind method

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

I have no trackpad so i cannot test but according to the mailing list it should work
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-April/003124.html

Try the test code, if events are being fired you can change the callback to move the scrollbar

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
t = Text(root)
t.pack()
t.bind('<MouseWheel>',lambda event:print(event))

root.mainloop()
```

As for the scrollbar - http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

t.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=t.yview)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the events still don't fire when I'm scrolling with the trackpad. The mouse cursor changes to scrolling cursor, but seems that tkinter doesn't feel this.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, read this, http://bugs.python.org/issue10731. Someone reports it working using the official python 3.4